# Java Gregorian calendar formatting

Tags: java, date, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I have a camping program that has a dialog box where the user inputs the date they are to check in and the date they plan to check out into a text field. Once they press ok on the dialog box, the dates they input should then be viewable in a JTable. Currently, in the date column I get a java.utl.GregorianCalendar[time....etc] when the user presses ok. The other information such as name, days staying, and site number appear okay. Obviously it is not formatting the date correctly, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the code for the Gregorian Calendar in the class DialogCheckInTent:

```
 public GregorianCalendar getDateIn(){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
     try{Date date = df.parse(dateIn.getText()); 
     g.setTime(date);
     }
     catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return g;
}

public GregorianCalendar getCheckOutDate(){
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    GregorianCalendar g = new GregorianCalendar();
     try{Date date = df.parse(checkOutTxt.getText()); 
     g.setTime(date);
     }
     catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    return g;
}
```

The above code is used in this method in the GUI when the user pressed okay.

```
 if (pressed == checkInTentItem) {
        newTent.clear();
        newTent.setVisible(true);
        if (model.getRowCount() < 5) {
            if (newTent.isOk()) {
                String nameReserving = newTent.getNameReserve();
                GregorianCalendar checkIn = newTent.getDateIn();
                int daysStaying = newTent.getDaysStaying();
                GregorianCalendar checkOutOn = newTent.getCheckOutDate();
                int siteNumber = newTent.getSiteNumber();
                int tenters = newTent.getTenters();
                Tent tent = new Tent(nameReserving, checkIn, daysStaying,
                        checkOutOn, siteNumber, tenters);
                model.add(tent);
            }

        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "All sites are full.",
                    " ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Everything compiles without a problem, but the date is just not working correctly. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
```

format is incorrect

months are represented with `M`, so change it to `MM/dd/yyyy`

also not sure what is the type for `pressed` and `checkInTentItem` for following condition

```
if (pressed == checkInTentItem) {
```

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

  Object pressed = evt.getSource();

Comment: I changed the formatting to MM, but still get the same error.

Comment: Object shouldn't be checked for equality by `==`, use `equals()` with proper implementation of `equals()` method

Comment: @TABmayfield Please accept this Answer if you perceive it as correct and resolving your Question. Hit the big empty green checkmark, if you see one.

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The [Answer by Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29086064/642706) is correct, and should be accepted.

The modern solution uses the `LocalDate` class. This class is part of the java.time classes that now supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `GregorianCalendar`, `Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat`.

Parse your input as a `LocalDate`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "11/29/2017" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).